# When is SBT expected to be ported to Scala 2.8?

Tags: scala, sbt

As far as I understand, current SBT release runs with Scala 2.7. When is it expected to migrate to Scala 2.8.1 (or a successor)?

Comment: why do you need SBT on 2.8? SBT on 2.7 can build your 2.8 project.

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter much, since the code _you_ write can be in other Scala versions.

Comment: I just hate it downloading 2.7 when 2.8 is installed in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 0.9 will be based on 2.8.1.  I don't know when it's coming out, but you can get it from GitHub.

http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/49d5b84c94339b66

http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/090p1tour

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/tree/0.9